# call a method from another method in Code behind C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, method-call

I need to call `btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` from another method `protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)` which normally calls by a button click.

Now here in `Timer1_Tick` compares a time and if current time exceeds, i need to call `btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` automatically.

```
  protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime et = DateTime.Parse(Session["endtime"].ToString());

        if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= et.TimeOfDay)
        {
           // btn_submit_Click();
            Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");

        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
    }
```

Please suggest me a way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would take a slightly different approach. You're not actually trying to say that a button was clicked - you're just interested in the same side effects as a button click. So extract a third method which only has the relevant parameters (there may not be any) and call that method from both `btn_submit_Click` and `Timer1_Tick`. That way you don't have to come up with a `sender` and `EventArgs` for a button click which didn't happen. So for example:

```
protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Maybe validation?
    Submit();
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime et = DateTime.Parse(Session["endtime"].ToString());

    if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= et.TimeOfDay)
    {
        Submit();
        Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
}

private void Submit()
{
    // Common code to execute on either the timer tick or button click
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Jon Skeet mentioned the right approach. Refactor the code in your `btn_submit_click` into a central method that can be called by both Button and Timer. But you can still do `submit_click(sender, e)`

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      ....
      btn_submit_Click(sender, e);
      ...
}
```